# Does Java allow passing a getter as a method parameter?

Tags: java, methods, parameter-passing

No Lambda, Predicate, Interface. Just a regular class with a regular getter. For example:

```
public int getWeight(){return weight;}

public int convertToLbs(int weight){some code here ...}


someObject.convertToLbs(someObject.getWeight())//valid???
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: You’re not passing a method reference in your example, you’re calling a getter and passing the returned value.

Comment: Yes, its allowed since it returns int its as good as passing integer to a method.

Comment: van dench  Thanks. Java use pass by value. Not sure what is method reference? Can you elaborate?

Comment: should be very easy to test... anyway, your call is kind of the same as `int w = someObject.getWeight(); someObject.convertToLbs(w);`

Comment: A method reference is where you pass a literal reference to a method, it is usually stored into an interface (with only one function) in Java. You can also pass a lambda or abstract class. What this means is that the receiver can choose when to call the function, this is useful for streams. A simple example would be that you have a method that receives a method which accepts two integers and returns an integer, you could pass a function that multiplies the values, adds the values, or does basically anything to the values, you just don’t know what 2 values you will be getting.

Comment: van dench Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current syntax is valid but you are passing the `weight` value because [Java is pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

To pass a method reference for something that returns `int` you can use `IntSupplier`:

```
public int getWeight() { return weight; }
public int convertToLbs(IntSupplier s) { int w = s.getAsInt(); ... }

someObject.convertToLbs(someObject::getWeight);
```